# Regarding convex functions that attain infimum at infinity

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, convex-optimization, scalar-fields

Let function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable, lower-bounded and convex. Let $\nabla f$ be the gradient of $f$, i.e., $\nabla f = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} \dots \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n} \end{bmatrix}$. If $x^1,x^2,\dots$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} f(x^i) = \inf_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} f(x)$$

then is the following true?

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left\| \nabla f(x^i) \right\| = 0$$

where $\|\cdot\|$ is the usual Euclidean norm. If this is not true, what additional assumptions on $f$ can be added so that this is true?

Thank you.

Comment: You haven't made any statements about the sequence $\{x^i\}$... if for example $x^* = argminf(x)$ exists, and if $x^i$ approaches $x^*$, then $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(x^i) = \inf_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} f(x)$ automatically

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I am especially interested in the case when $\mathrm{argmin} f$ is empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take $n=2$ and consider $f(t_1,t_2) = \max(e^{-t_1}, |t_2|)$.  Being the maximum of two convex functions, this is convex.  The points $x^i = (i, 2 e^{-i})$ have $f(x^i) = 2 e^{-i} \to 0 = \inf f$, but $|\nabla f(x^i)| = 1$.

This example is not continuously differentiable, but can be smoothed.

Comment: Beautiful counterexample, thank you!